# ScrollView is not scrolling my TextView

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I Solved the problem with this link. I needed to create seperate activitoes with seperate java and xml files. The link below did. it. Thanks everyone for your help.

http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/09/android-switching-between-activities-example.html

Comment: Can you post more of the Layout? You seem to be missing the scrollview.

Comment: try the scrollview inside the linear layout.
should be like this:
<linear>
<scrollview>
<textview>
</textview>
</scrollview>
</linear>

Comment: So that others can learn from your question, it would be better to leave it in its original and post an answer to it instead of replacing your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this line:

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

Replace it with this:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

You're currently restricting your scrollable space to only 200dp with that line.

Also, as TGMCians pointed out, you need to set in your TextView:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Instead of explicitly setting a value.

Comment: ... and set the height of `textview` to wrapcontent. OP giving child views height more than parent layout which is completely wrong

Comment: @user3320301 did you try this? Layouts in Android are painful at times.

Answer (score 0):

You set the `height` of the `ScrollView` to `200dp`, try replacing with this:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:fillViewport="true">

      <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           ...

      </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried that. My text still doesn't scroll. Also, there are three buttons across the bottom of the screen. When I click the button that shows my scrolling text, two buttons disappear, but one remains. The text will not scroll, but it does show on top of the one button that doesn't dissappear. any ideas?

Comment: Could you post you entire code and perhaps your class too?